# How to wrap a span with a link using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a span. It has a class. I'm trying to wrap a link ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) around it.

`<span class="commentCount">0 Comments</span>`

Here's what I've tried in the documentReady JS:

```
   var commentspan = $("span.commentCount");

   if (windowURL.indexOf('s_post_submission=success') > -1) {
     alert('Test');
   commentspan.wrap('<a></a>');
```

The 'Test' alert pops up but the wrapping doesn't happen.

How can I get 'span' to turn into a hyperlink for example.com with jQuery/JS code?

Comment: commentspan.wrap('<a href="http://www.example.com"></a>');

Comment: That still has no effect on the page or the source code for some reason...maybe my problem is different than the syntax

Comment: Are you getting errors in your web browser's console or anything?  There's a syntax error in your original javascript.  The curly bracket { is never closed.  You could either close that bracket or remove the { entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working snippet.

```js
var commentspan = $("span.commentCount");
commentspan.wrap('<a href="http://www.example.com"></a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="commentCount">0 Comments</span>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have no idea what's going wrong. If I do `alert(commentspan.text());` should I get a popup saying "0 comments'? It comes up blank.

Comment: Yes, it should popup "0 Comments".  Are you sure JQuery is being loaded properly?  This JSFiddle should popup the same alert message https://jsfiddle.net/yjebt7a5/ and those references should resolve.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think I understand what OTHER issue in my source code is causing this. Thank you very much for the help and getting me looking in the right direction rather than stuck on actually-correct syntax for hours.